# How can i Optimize my sql query

Tags: sql

[image]

[image]

I have a the table above calls and user and i have this query

to get the incoming and outgoing

```
      SELECT username ,
      ( Select count(*) from calls where type = 'incoming' and user_id = user.id) as incoming,
      ( Select count(*) from calls where type = 'outgoing' and user_id = user.id) as outgoing
      from user
      join calls on user.id = calls.user_id
      group by user_id
```

i got the correct data but is there much better way to do this query?

this the result of the query

[image]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
 select u.username,
        sum(case when c.type = 'incoming' then 1 else 0 end) as  incoming,
        sum(case when c.type = 'outgoing' then 1 else 0 end) as  outgoing
 from user u join
      calls c
      on u.id = c.user_id
 group by u.username;
```

Note other changes:

- The tables have abbreviations, called table aliases.
- All columns are qualified, so they identify the table they are coming from.
- The `group by` column matches the `select` column.

Comment: is your solution much faster ?

Comment: @vladawtsu . . . I can't answer that, only you can.  It should be much faster, though, because it is only doing the aggregation without the correlated subqueries.